# In rke kube-proxy pod is not present

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, bare-metal, kube-proxy, rke

in my RKE cluster(v1.3.14) there is no kube-proxy pod but kube-proxy container then how I install metallb give any solution for that

.it is possible to install without kube-proxy pod then how??

Give me solution if someone faces same issue